# changes to the domain class does not reflect changes to the view in grails app

Tags: grails

I was wondering why the create page of my domain class won't reflect the changes that I did on  my domain class. I tried adding some extra fields but it just won't appear on the UI.

I also tried changing the order the fields that are typed in on the *static constraints = {}* closure but to no avail and they still look the same order as before I did the change

Also tried *grails clean*, nothing happened

I am pretty sure I am in the right directory and I am using the development environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you created your scaffolding by executing the generate-all command you are using static scaffolding. If you are using static scaffolding you will have to re-execute the generate-all command after modifying your domain class. Static scaffolding is meant as a template that you can modify for your needs. It is not meant to automatically change when your domain class does. Dynamic scaffolding will change when your domain class changes but offers less customization ability. In general static scaffolding is better for custom UI while dynamic scaffolding works well for things such as admin pages that most users won't see.

Comment: yeah, that is the second time I forgot I am already doing the static scaffolding. gee, but thanks for the answer. appreciate it.

Comment: and one more question please? could I still be able to use the grails security plugins like jsecurity, shiro and spring security while I am doing the dynamic scaffolding? :D